# limit to insert rows into a table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle pl/sql, I have join few tables and insert into another table, which would result in Thousands/Lakhs or it could be in millions. Can insert as

```
insert into tableA
select * from tableB;
```

Will there be any chance of failure because of number of rows ?
Or is there a better way to insert values in case of more no of records.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One uses a relational database so that you don't have to repeat data by normalizing it into separate table and join them as needed with filters. Creating a product table is counter to this philosophy. If you want to obfuscate the join, use a VIEW instead of creating another table.

Comment: Is this a production system? Does the data need to be recoverable from a previous backup in case of media failure later on? do you have enough disk space?

Comment: @David : Yes, its a production system. We would have the records max in Lakhs not in Milliions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, everything is finite inside the machine, so if that select returns too many rows, it for sure won't work (although there must be maaany rows, the number is dependent on your storage and memory size, your OS, and maybe other things).

If you think your query can surpass the limit, then do the insertion in batches, and commit after each batch. Of course you need to be aware you must do something if at 50% of the inserts you decide you need to cancel the process (as a `rollback` will not be useful here).

Comment: Can we use Bulk collect option ?

Comment: For BULK you need to put everything in a variable first, so again, if you have too many rows you will hit problems if you try to do it in a single call. I'd recommend you check if you really have a large number of rows, maybe you are underestimating your system (as even millions of rows can be a simple task to perform for Oracle in some machine setups). If you are not underestimating it, then go for sure: do batch inserts by committing every X rows.

Comment: I don't see how the maximum size of the result set is dependent on the OS ... maybe memory, certainly available disk space.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I was thinking of maximum in-memory data that a process can maintain. But maybe I'm wrong about that one as there are workarounds for that problem, it was more of a guess.

Answer (score 1):

My recommended steps are different because performance typically increases when you load more data in one SQL statement using SQL or PL/SQL:

1. I would recommend checking the size of your rollback segment (RBS segment) and possibly bring online a larger dedicated one for such transaction.
2. For inserts, you can say something like 'rollback consumed' = 'amount of data inserted'. You know the typical row width from the database statistics (see user_tables after `analyze table tableB compute statistics for table for all columns for all indexes`).
3. Determine how many rows you can insert per iteration.
4. Insert this amount of data in big insert and commit.
5. Repeat.
6. Locking normally is not an issue with insert, since what does not yet exist can't be locked :-)

When running on partitioned tables, you might want to consider different scenarios allowing the (sub)partitions to distribute the work together. When using SQL*Loader by loading from text files, you might use different approach too, such as direct path which adds preformatted data blocks to the database without the SQL engine instead of letting the RDBMS handle the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To create limited number of rows you can use ROW_NUM  which is a pseudo column  .

for example to create table with 10,000 rows from another table having 50,000 rows you can use.

```
insert into new_table_name select * from old_table_name where row_num<10000;
```